# siamltx + amsthm: "LaTeX Error: No counter 'Theorem' defined."

Tags: counters, incompatibility, amsthm

When using the LaTeX class `siamltx` (from [the SIAM page](https://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php)) together with [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) (which I need for its `theoremstyle` command), I'm getting the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'Theorem' defined.
```

The following code reproduces the error.

```
\documentclass{siamltex}                                                        

\let\proof\relax                                                                
\let\endproof\relax                                                             
\usepackage{amsthm}                                                             

\begin{document}                                                                

\begin{theorem}                                                                 
dasdas                                                                          
\end{theorem}                                                                   

\end{document}
```

Any way around this?

Comment: I'm afraid `siamltex` is not compatible with `amsthm`, because it redefines macros such as `\@begintheorem` in a way that `amsthm` can't deal with.

Comment: @Jubobs exactly which macros in your list indicate amsthm? \newtheorem is a part of latex core

Comment: @daleif You're absolutely right! I always thought `\newtheorem` was defined by the `amsthm` package. My mistake. I'll delete my earlier comment.

Comment: @Jubobs, trick use `texdoc source2e` to see what is in the core.

Answer (score 5):

This class already defines the theorem environment, but `amsthm` redefines some (but not all) of the internal commands used in that definition (notably `\@thm`). This completely messes things up. For this reason, `amsthm` cannot be loaded under `siamltex.cls`. Sometimes, loading the package before the document class works. This can be done with

```
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\documentclass{siamltex}
```

Unfortunately, the reverse problem occurs: `siamltex` redefines an internal macro of `amsthm`'s version of the `theorem` environment (`\@begintheorem`) and messes it up.

The only work-around is not to use these two together. The class defines the various theorem-like environments already, as well as the `proof` environment, and does so in the ways the SIAM publishers chose, so there seems to be no reason for `amsthm`.